# Can a qubit be collapsed repeatedly?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-measurements

So I know a qubit collapses after measurement. Now since each eigen state can be represented as a superposition of eigen states in another basis, does that mean measuring a qubit on different eigen states interchangeably will continuously cause a wave collapse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you measure a system in basis A you have put the system into an eigenstate of basis A. But an eigenstate of basis A is simply a superposition of eigenstates in another basis B. So if you now measure the same system in basis B, you put it into an eigenstate of basis B - but this is no longer (in general) an eigenstate of basis A. And if you measure the system for a second time in basis A you may get a result that is different from your first measurement (no matter how short you make the interval between the measurements).

Comment: I would have been even more pleased with  a mathematical illustration but I can't be too greedy :).
Still this makes sense for me, thanks!